# Why am I getting 'The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined' when running vite build but vite works ok?

Tags: vite

I have the [following PR](https://github.com/purejgleason/example-vue-vite/pull/4) when I test locally the `vite` command works fine but the `vite build` command fails in the same way the github action is failing. Why would `vite build` throw...

```
~/Code/personal/example-vue-vite on REMOVE_CDN>npx vite build
vite v3.1.4 building for production...
error during build:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:377:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:1098:7)
    at resolve (file:///.../example-vue-vite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b3a5aff.js:45670:35)
    at doBuild (file:///.../example-vue-vite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b3a5aff.js:45672:43)
    at async build (file:///.../example-vue-vite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-6b3a5aff.js:45654:16)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///.../example-vue-vite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:748:9)
```

```
build: {
    minify: true,
    soucemap: "inline",
    lib: {
      name: 'index',
      formats: ['es'],
    }
  },
```

What am I missing how do I get the `vite build` to work?

Also to be clear the `Vitest` tests work fine even in Github Actions, only the build is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the issue is with the way my vite was configured. I needed the following...

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, resolve } from 'path';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
```

Then I needed to change my lib like this...

```
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.mjs'),
      fileName: "exampleApp",
      name: "exampleApp",
      formats: ['es'],
    }
```

Now it builds correctly